# Загрузка нескольких файлов, множественный выбор

Tags: файлы, http, fileupload

Мне нужно загрузить много файлов на сервер с UI, и делать это необходимо за раз. Файлов может быть много например 20, и создавать 20 инпутов как то не хочется.

В интернете полно примеров. Вот таких. Но в них используется для кадого файла отдельный `<input`, мне это ненужно.

```
<form action="/someAction" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Файлы:<br />
  <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br />
  <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br />
  <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Отправить" />
</form>
```

Мне нужно чтобы был один `input`, но в нем можно было выбирать сразу хоть 100 файлов.

Возможно это сделать, и с помощью чего, и если будет пример валидации файлов например на тип формата, то будет замечательно.

Comment: Попробуйте просто добавить в поле атрибут `multiple`, а валидацию формата можно обеспечить атрибутом `accept`: `<input name="files" type="file" multiple accept="image/*">`

Answer (score 2):

*Из комментария пользователя [@SergeyGornostaev](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/204271/sergey-gornostaev):*

Добавьте в поле атрибут `multiple`, а валидацию формата можно обеспечить атрибутом `accept`:

```
<input name="files" type="file" multiple accept="image/*">
```